# Replacing text only in lines that match a criteria, using the pipeline

Tags: powershell

My goal is to replace specific texts in specific lines in a text file, and I want to do that using the pipeline.

At first, I tried to write the code for the text replacement, without the condition that set the replacement to happen only in specific lines:

```
$fileName = Read-Host "Enter the full path of the file, without quotes"
(Get-Content -Path $fileName -Encoding UTF8) |
  ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "01", "January " } |
  Set-Content -Path $fileName -Encoding UTF8
```

It seems that it works. But then, I inserted an IF statement to the pipeline:

```
$fileName = Read-Host "Enter the full path of the file, without quotes"
(Get-Content -Path $fileName -Encoding UTF8) |
  ForEach-Object { if ($_ -match "Month") {$_ -replace "03", "March"} } |
  Set-Content -Path $fileName -Encoding UTF8
```

When I ran the last script, at the end of the process I got a file that includes only the lines that matched the `if` Statement. If I'm understanding correctly what happened, it seems that only the lines that match the `if` statement are passed to the next stage in the pipeline. So I understand why the output of the process, but I still can't figure how to solve this - How to pass all the lines in the files through all the stages of the pipeline, but to still make the text replacements to happen only in specific lines that match a specific criteria.
Could you please assist me with this issue?

Please notice that I would like not to use a temporary file for this and also remember that I prefer an elegant way of doing this, using the pipeline.

Comment: `if(...){...}else{$_}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `else` statement like:

```
(Get-Content -Path $fileName -Encoding UTF8) | 
    Foreach-Object { If ($_ - match "Month")  { $_ -replace "03", "March"} else { $_ }  } | 
    Set-Content -Path $fileName - Encoding UTF8
```

Without `else` you didn't put line in pipeline. So your `if` was like filter

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your input data looks like you may not need a nested conditional (or a `ForEach-Object`) at all. If your input looks for instance like this:

```
Month: 03
```

you can do the replacement like this:

```
(Get-Content -Path $fileName -Encoding UTF8) -replace '^(.*Month.*)03','$1March' |
  Set-Content -Path $fileName -Encoding UTF8
```

That will modify just the lines matching the pattern (`^(.*Month.*)03`) and leave everything else unchanged.